# HashMap from List of Files

Tags: java, hashmap

I'd like to explore the option of using a HashMap to keep track of changes between files. I'm using a few config/text files to give a set of documents of status:

The config file looks like:

```
STATUS1 = "Doc1.pdf, Doc2.xls, Doc5.doc"
STATUS2 = "Doc8.pdf, Doc6.doc"
STATUS3 = "Doc10.pdf"
...
```

Instead of having to create a separate HashMap for each instance like so:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

map1.put("STATUS1", "Doc1.pdf");
map2.put("STATUS1", "Doc2.xls");
map3.put("STATUS1", "Doc5.doc");
```

I'd like to have only a single Map with the key of the status and the values mapped to that key.

I don't need help in parsing the file, I just need assistance in implementing the HashMap or Map so I can add this functionality. If there are other datatypes or methods of organizing this data, I'd like to hear your opinions on that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why are you reinventing diff?

Comment: @Brian, I'm only trying to implement some functionality that diff uses, however I need a "Status" associated with the changes and I'm not overly familiar with diff to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html), which stores multiple values for the same key.

1. **Multimap**

> ```
>    Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
>    // Adding some key/value
>
>   myMultimap.put("STATUS1", "somePDF");
>   myMultimap.put("STATUS1", "someDOC");
>   myMultimap.put("STATUS1", "someXCL");   
>   myMultimap.put("STATUS2","someFormat");
>
>   // Getting the size
>   int size = myMultimap.size();
>   System.out.println(size);  // 4
>
>   // Getting values
>   Collection<string> stats1 = myMultimap.get("STATUS1");
>   System.out.println(stats1); // [somePDF, someDOC, someXCL]
> ```

2 . **HashMap**

```
With HashMap you can have something like,

    List<String> listOfDocs = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOfDocs.add("somePDF");
    listOfDocs.add("someDOC");
    listOfDocs.add("someFormat");

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>(); 
    // key would be your STATUS
    // Values would be ListOfDocs you need.

   map.put("STATUS1", listOfDocs);
   map.put("STATUS2", listOfDocs2);
   map.put("STATUS3", listOfDocs3);
```

Hope this helps.
Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I would assume you're using the Google Collections library instead of the Apache collection, correct?

Comment: @Signus for using MultiMap yes.

Comment: Awesome. Great implementation. Note for anyone using Apache Commons - use "MultiMap<U, V> [name] = new MultiValueMap<U, V>();"